# URL to `/` within a subdomain - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, subdomain, laravel-5.3

I use subdomain functionality in Laravel 5.3.
My main app address has format `http://example.com`
When within a subdomain such as `http://dev.example.com`I use same templates for header.

### problem

as a result, the head of my page, which contains url to homepage, defined in blade as `{{URL::to('/')}}` renders as `http://dev.example.com`, while desired is `http://example.com`

### to do

is there any good practice to get make Laravel show the main domain URLs?
I could add a variable in controller used for subdomain purposes, but it seems not really professional way to solve the issue.

Comment: Looking around the source there doesn't seem to be much you can do, I would personally override the `UrlGenerator` class and add a method that uses the root of the current subdomain.

Comment: Have you tried with named routes?

Answer (score 0):

I find this easier to do on the vhost/htaccess level to redirect the user to the required domain instead of trying to work in the code for this, have the webserver redirect you before any code execution happens.

Hope that helps

Thanks,

//P